# C - 3 problems with Segmentation fault when try to return string

Tags: c, string, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have 3 problems but I think they're essentially the same.

I have 3 functions that are doing something on the String they get as parameter, but when I try to return the result, I get a segmentation fault every time and I can't understand why.

```
/* the function gets a string, and return the string without blank spaces (is exists) in the end of the string */
char *trimRightSpaces(char *str, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int i = len;
    char *trimStr = NULL;

    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

        while(i > 0)
    {
        if(isspace((int)str[i]))
                    break;
        i--;
    }

    strncpy(trimStr, str, i-1);
    trimStr[i+1] = '\0';
    return trimStr;
}
```

and this function gets labels from my program, that are just strings with ':' character in the end:

```
/* The function gets a pointer to a string, and returns the name of label without ':' if it's a valid label, NULL if not. */
char *isLabel(char *str)
{
    int i;
    char tempStr[80];

    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(strlen(str) > VALID_LABEL_LENGTH)
        return NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            /* if the first letter of the string is not small or capital letter, then it's not a valid label. */
            if(!isalpha((int)str[0]))
                return NULL;
        }

        if(i == (strlen(str) - 1))
        {
                if((int)str[i] != ':') /* check it the word ends with ':', otherwise it's not a valid label */
                    return NULL;
                break;
        }

        if(!isalnum((int)str[i]))
            return NULL;
    }

    strncpy(tempStr, str, strlen(str) - 1);

    if(isLanguageWord(tempStr))
        return NULL;

    return str;
}
```

and:

```
/* the function get a string, and check if it's a valid string: a string inside " ". if it's valid, it returns the string without " ", and NULL otherwise. */
char *validString(char *str)
{
    char temp[80];
    char *temp2 = NULL;
    int i;

    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(str[0] != '"' || str[strlen(str) - 1] != '"')
        return NULL;

    for(i = 1; i < strlen(str) - 1; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = str[i];
    }
    temp2 = temp;
    return temp2;
}
```

Comment: Where the deuce is the memory allocated for `trimStr` in your first snippet?

Comment: In first one there is no string. It is not allocated, just a NULL pointer. Lazy to go over the rest, but evidently you need to revise what you know about working with pointers.

Comment: `char *trimStr = NULL; ... strncpy(trimStr, str, i-1);` --> Attempting to write data to an invalid location.

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to a stack based array from the `validString` function, because it goes out of scope after the function returns. All functions have the same problems, yes. You are either not allocating any strings, or you are writing to NULL pointers. Also, `str[i]` will read out of bounds when `i == len`.

Comment: The correct type for array sizes is `size_t`; better to use this than `unsigned int`....

Comment: `isalnum((int)str[i])` --> `isalnum((unsigned char)str[i])`

Answer (score 1):

in the function:

```
char *validString(char *str)
```

this statement:

```
temp2 = temp;
```

is setting the pointer to point to a local variable.

Then this statement:

```
return temp2;
```

is returning that pointer.

The problem is when the local variable 'goes out of scope' (which happens when the function exits.) that stack variable no longer is usable.

accessing the contents of that variable in the calling function is undefined behavior.

I.E. the function can be reduced to :

```
/* the function get a string, and check if it's a valid string: a string inside " ". if it's valid, it returns the string without " ", and NULL otherwise. */
char *validString(char *str)
{
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(str[0] != '"' || str[strlen(str) - 1] != '"')
        return NULL;

    return strdup( str );
} // end function: validString
```

the function: `trimRightSpaces()` does not actually trim the trailing spaces AND has the same problem as the `validString()` function.  Suggest:

```
/* the function gets a string, and return the string without blank spaces (is exists) in the end of the string */
char *trimRightSpaces( char *str )
{
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    size_t i;
    for( i = strlen( str ); i > 0 && ' ' == str[i]; i-- );

    char *trimstr = strdup( str );

    if( trimstr )
        trimstr[i] = '\0';  // note: this may need to be [i+1]

    return trimstr;
}  // end function: trimRightSpaces
```

the function: `islabel()` has the same problem AND a few other problems.  Suggest:

```
/* The function gets a pointer to a string, and returns the name of label without ':' if it's a valid label, NULL if not. */
char *isLabel(char *str)
{
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(strlen(str) > VALID_LABEL_LENGTH)
        return NULL;

    if(isLanguageWord(str))  // note: this 'may' not work, but function not posted so don't know
        return NULL;

    if(str[strlen( str ) -1] != ':') /* check it the word ends with ':', otherwise it's not a valid label */
        return NULL;

    /* if the first letter of the string is not small or capital letter, then it's not a valid label. */
    if(!isalpha((int)str[0]))
        return NULL;

    for( size_t i = strlen(str); i ; i-- )
    {
        if(!isalnum((int)str[i]))
            return NULL;
    }

    return strdup( str );
} // end function: isLabel
```

Comment: Note: this line: `for( i = strlen( str ); i > 0 && ' ' == str[i]; i-- );` is assuming that there is (at least) one non space character in the string.

Comment: you will need to `free` the strings return by these functions

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems in your code.

For example, if you declate pointer to char

```
char *trimStr = NULL;   // Points to NULL, cant dereference
char *trimStr;          // Uninitialized ptr, cant dereference
```

then you cant dereference `NULL` or uninitialized pointer. Whats worse you are trying to copy data inside. What you have to do is allocate enough memory on heap, for example

```
char *trimStr = malloc(len);
```

Then you can copy `len` bytes into trimStr.

Second, you cant return pointer to local variable like you do in `validString` because after program counter returns back from function, the frame is destroyed and local variable is out of scope -> no more reachable. You have to return pointer to allocated memory on heap or pass an pointer to array to function, where you will fill this array.

Also i can see some *logical* problems like

```
if(isspace((int)str[i]))
```

Where you want to trim spaces but `isspace` returns non-zero if its space. So you have to negate the expression

```
if(!isspace((int)str[i]))
```

**[Here is the example of trimRightSpaces function.](https://ideone.com/1pxvZT)**